# Reproduce Python 2 PyQt4 QImage constructor behavior in Python 3

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-3.x, pyqt4, qimage

I have written a small GUI using PyQt4 that displays an image and gets point coordinates that the user clicks on.  I need to display a 2D numpy array as a grayscale, so I am creating a QImage from the array, then from that creating a QPixmap.  In Python 2 it works fine.

When I moved to Python 3, however, it can't decide on a constructor for QImage - it gives me the following error:

```
TypeError: arguments did not match any overloaded call:
  QImage(): too many arguments
  QImage(QSize, QImage.Format): argument 1 has unexpected type 'numpy.ndarray'
  QImage(int, int, QImage.Format): argument 1 has unexpected type 'numpy.ndarray'
  QImage(str, int, int, QImage.Format): argument 1 has unexpected type 'numpy.ndarray'
  QImage(sip.voidptr, int, int, QImage.Format): argument 1 has unexpected type 'numpy.ndarray'
  QImage(str, int, int, int, QImage.Format): argument 1 has unexpected type 'numpy.ndarray'
  QImage(sip.voidptr, int, int, int, QImage.Format): argument 1 has unexpected type 'numpy.ndarray'
  QImage(list-of-str): argument 1 has unexpected type 'numpy.ndarray'
  QImage(str, str format=None): argument 1 has unexpected type 'numpy.ndarray'
  QImage(QImage): argument 1 has unexpected type 'numpy.ndarray'
  QImage(object): too many arguments
```

As far as I can tell, the QImage constructor I was calling previously was one of these:

- `QImage(str, int, int, QImage.Format)`
- `QImage(sip.voidptr, int, int, QImage.Format)`

I'm assuming that a numpy array fits one of the protocols necessary for one of these.  I'm thinking it might have to do with an array versus a view, but all the variations I've tried either produce the above error or just make the GUI exit without doing anything.  **How can I reproduce the Python 2 behavior in Python 3?**

The following is a small example, in which the same exact code works fine under Python 2 but not Python 3:

```
from __future__ import (print_function, division)

from PyQt4 import QtGui, QtCore
import numpy as np

class MouseView(QtGui.QGraphicsView):

    mouseclick = QtCore.pyqtSignal(tuple)

    def __init__(self, scene, parent=None):
        super(MouseView, self).__init__(scene, parent=parent)

    def mousePressEvent(self, event):
        self.mouseclick.emit((event.x(),
                              self.scene().sceneRect().height() - event.y()))


class SimplePicker(QtGui.QDialog):

    def __init__(self, data, parent=None):
        super(SimplePicker, self).__init__(parent)

        mind = data.min()
        maxd = data.max()
        bdata = ((data - mind) / (maxd - mind) * 255.).astype(np.uint8)

        wdims = data.shape
        wid = wdims[0]
        hgt = wdims[1]

        # This is the line of interest - it works fine under Python 2, but not Python 3
        img = QtGui.QImage(bdata.T, wid, hgt,
                           QtGui.QImage.Format_Indexed8)

        self.scene = QtGui.QGraphicsScene(0, 0, wid, hgt)
        self.px = self.scene.addPixmap(QtGui.QPixmap.fromImage(img))

        view = MouseView(self.scene)
        view.setHorizontalScrollBarPolicy(QtCore.Qt.ScrollBarAlwaysOff)
        view.setVerticalScrollBarPolicy(QtCore.Qt.ScrollBarAlwaysOff)
        view.setSizePolicy(QtGui.QSizePolicy.Fixed,
                           QtGui.QSizePolicy.Fixed)
        view.setMinimumSize(wid, hgt)
        view.mouseclick.connect(self.click_point)

        quitb = QtGui.QPushButton("Done")
        quitb.clicked.connect(self.quit)

        lay = QtGui.QVBoxLayout()
        lay.addWidget(view)
        lay.addWidget(quitb)

        self.setLayout(lay)

        self.points = []

    def click_point(self, xy):
        self.points.append(xy)

    def quit(self):
        self.accept()


def test_picker():

    x, y = np.mgrid[0:100, 0:100]
    img = x * y

    app = QtGui.QApplication.instance()
    if app is None:
        app = QtGui.QApplication(['python'])

    picker = SimplePicker(img)
    picker.show()
    app.exec_()

    print(picker.points)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    test_picker()
```

I am using an Anaconda installation on Windows 7 64-bit, Qt 4.8.7, PyQt 4.10.4, numpy 1.9.2.

Comment: You need an object that supports the [buffer protocol](https://docs.python.org/3.5/c-api/buffer.html#index-0). For python2, this a `buffer` object, but for python3 it's a `memoryview`. Using `bdata.data` will work in your example for both python2 and python3, but, frustratingly, `bdata.T.data` does *not* work with python3. Which is totally baffling, given that the error now is `unexpected type 'memoryview'`?! It seems that there is some subtle difference between the two memoryviews that PyQt is not able to handle.

Comment: Thanks for the info!  I tried `bdata.data`, and it doesn't give any errors, but it doesn't run the GUI either!  An empty list gets printed from `test_picker`, but no GUI appears.  Is there something else wrong with the rest of the example?

Comment: The GUI works fine for me with just `QtGui.QImage(bdata.data, ...`, but it does dump core on exit. That can easily be fixed by giving the scene a parent, though: `QGraphicsScene(0, 0, wid, hgt, self)`. Other than that, I can't think why it doesn't work for you. What platform are you on, and what versions of Qt, PyQt and numpy are you using?

Comment: @ekhumoro Sorry for the long delay, I ended up out of town at a meeting for a few days.  I'm on Windows 7 64 bit, Anaconda installation, with Qt 4.8.7, PyQt 4.10.4, numpy 1.6.2 (added to question)

Comment: I also just noticed that if I move the contents of `test_picker` directly under the `if __name__ ==...`, then the GUI does show up (using `bdata.data`), but it also prints the empty list before I exit the GUI (no points are saved).  Python 2 still works like I want it to.  ARGH.

Comment: I think you need to properly debug your example script before you try to isolate the numpy issue. I suggest you start by commenting out **all** the numpy/image related stuff and just aim to get a simple graphics view that records clicks. Then make sure it runs cleanly on both Python 2 and Python 3 (e.g. no spewing error messages or dumping core on exit). Once you have that, you can start adding back the numpy/image related stuff and try to pin-point where the real issue is.

Comment: Agreed; I've been doing just that, and the empty list/GUI issue is actually due to the QDialog not *blocking* in Python 3 when run from **ipython qtconsole** (vanilla ipython is fine --> is a different thing altogether).  As for the QImage, pretty much if I give it a Numpy view, it dies (both 2 and 3), and if I give it an array (using `.copy()`) it's fine (both 2 and 3).  Turns out that `.T` is an exception that somehow just *happens* to work with Python 2, for some unknown reason.

Comment: I'm putting together an answer that documents this with one solution: use `.copy()` ...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the PyQt constructor above, the following behavior is observed from a Numpy array called `bdata`:

- `bdata` works correctly for both Python 2 and Python 3
- `bdata.T` works for 2, not for 3 (constructor error)
- `bdata.T.copy()` works for both
- `bdata[::-1,:]` does not work for either 2 or 3 (the same error)
- `bdata[::-1,:].copy()` works for both
- `bdata[::-1,:].base` works for both, but loses the result of the reverse operation

As mentioned by @ekhumoro in the comments, you need something which supports the Python [buffer protocol](https://docs.python.org/3.5/c-api/buffer.html#buffer-protocol).  The actual Qt constructor of interest here is [this](http://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/qimage.html) QImage constructor, or the const version of it:

```
QImage(uchar * data, int width, int height, Format format)
```

From the PyQt 4.10.4 documentation kept [here](https://dada.cs.washington.edu/doc/PyQt4-devel-4.10.1/html/gotchas.html), what PyQt expects for an `unsigned char *` is different in Python 2 and 3:

Python 2:

> If Qt expects a `char *`, `signed char *` or an `unsigned char *` (or a const version) then PyQt4 will accept a unicode or QString that contains only ASCII characters, a str, a QByteArray, or a **Python object that implements the buffer protocol**.

Python 3:

> If Qt expects a `signed char *` or an `unsigned char *` (or a const version) then PyQt4 will accept a **bytes**.

A Numpy *array* satisfies both of these, but apparently a Numpy *view* doesn't satisfy either.  It's actually baffling that `bdata.T` works at all in Python 2, as it purportedly returns a view:

```
>>> a = np.ones((2,3))
>>> b = a.T
>>> b.base is a
True
```

**The final answer:** If you need to do transformations that result in a view, you can avoid errors by doing a `copy()` of the result to a new array for passing into the constructor.  This may not be the best answer, but it will work.

Comment: What's baffling to me is that `type(bdata) is type(bdata.T)` returns true, and yet they are not really the same thing. That is why I got the contradictory error message `unexpected type 'memoryview'` when trying to use `bdata.T.data`. It's clearly not the actual *type* of the object that is unexpected - some other property of an ndarray view vs a copy must undermine pyqt's automatic conversion process.

Comment: Agreed.  I have no idea why the internals are so different from pyqt's perspective ... perhaps only a pyqt dev could shed light on this particular quirk.